# CardView игнорирует CornerRadius

Tags: android, recyclerview

Делаю список через `RecyclerView` и `CardView`. Всё работает, кроме скругления углов, Вот их разметки:

**UPDATE**
Спустя некоторое время выяснил, что всё это из-за того, что в адапторе для ActionMode задаю цвет Background. Что также меняет и внешний вид CardView. Как правильно менять цвет, что бы он не изменять вид Cardview?

```
  holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.recycleviewBackground));


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/cardView"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!--  Recycler View  -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewItemList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: а версия зависимости в gradle какая?

Comment: @TimurMukhortov    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'

Comment: а попробуйте обновить в каком нибудь тестовом бранче, интересно просто может ли быть в этой причина, у меня сейчас просто 27.1.1 и все ок, единственное что проблема с shadowcolor не работает у card view

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
app:contentPadding="10dp"
```

[Подробнее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493417/what-is-xml-property-xmlnsapp) на английском стеке

Comment: Оно всё есть, только cardView вместо app

Comment: ну так замените на арр

Comment: это лишь название переменной, оно значение не имеет. поскольку тени работают